English formatting for english bibliography entries
For an upcoming thesis, my professor asked me to adhere to his reference guidelines.
Among others, this includes formatting native (ngerman) entries in a different way than english publications.
Specifically, I need the bibliography to say pp. instead of S. (german "Seiten" for pages), "and" instead of "und" aswell as Eds. instead of Hrsg. (german "Herausgeber"...). This should happen for every entry regardless of type (article, inproceedings, book...).
I have already tried autolang=hyphen and language=autobib with \usepackage[USenglish, ngerman]{babel} according to this and this post, however this doesn't seem to change anything yet (or, more realistically, I'm not completely getting it...)
Below is a MWE of it not working as intended.
Thank you very much in advance!
\begin{filecontents}{mixedlanguages.bib}
@book{GermanBib,
  title = {Vorräte richtig schützen und lagern in Landwirtschaft, Verarbeitung und Handel},
  author = {Adler, Cornel and Kühne, Stefan},
  date = {2021},
  publisher = {Eugen Ulmer},
  pages= {100-200},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  isbn = {978-3-8186-0921-4},
  langid = {german}
}

@incollection{EnglishBib,
  title = {Temperature, effects on development and growth},
  booktitle = {Encyclopedia of {{Insects}}},
  author = {Nedved, Oldrich},
  editor = {Resh, Vincent H. and Cardé, Ring T.},
  date = {2009},
  pages = {990--992},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  location = {San Diego, Kalifornien, USA},
  langid = {english},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[    backend=biber,
                style=authoryear,
                giveninits=true,
                autolang=hyphen,
                language=autobib,
                ]{biblatex}
                
\addbibresource{mixedlanguages.bib}

\begin{document}

I need to cite \parencite{GermanBib} using the german style (S. for Seiten/pages)\\
%\citep{example} > throws an error
I also need to cite \parencite{EnglishBib} using the english style (pp. for multiple pages and Eds. for Editors)\\

\printbibliography

\end{document}


use autolang=langname,.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you very much!

A few seconds after posting, I read this question with an answer by gnucchi a little more carefully. For everyone attempting to do the same thing, change the autolang=hyphen to autolang=other. It can be so easy sometimes!
Edit: Ulrike Fischer pointed out that the use of autolang=langname works aswell, and probably is designated for this use. Thanks, Ulrike!

If you use babel, both autolang=other, and autolang=langname, do the same. If you use polyglossia, autolang=langname, will select the language environments named after the language and autolang=other, will select the otherlanguage environment (which according to the polyglossia docs are equivalent).

@moewe Thank you for clarifying!
